# How to expose custom object in web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

How can I expose an custom object as parameter in a class using web services?

For example, I have a class called `OrderWS.java` and in that class I have `OrderLineWS.java` as parameter. Now when I exposed this `OrderWS.java` to web services on client side. It did not include `OrderLineWS` as parameter to `OrderWS` class on client side. Can anybody help me please?

OrderWS.java

```
package com.dev.backend.order;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.dev.backend.customer.CustomerWS;

public class OrderWS implements Serializable{

    private String orderNumber;
    private String customerCode ;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    private List<OrderLineWS> orderLineWSs = new ArrayList<OrderLineWS>();

    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }
    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }
    public String getCustomerCode() {
        return customerCode;
    }
    public void setCustomerCode(String customerCode) {
        this.customerCode = customerCode;
    }
    public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }
    public void setTotalPrice(BigDecimal totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }
    public List<OrderLineWS> getOrderLineWSs() {
        return orderLineWSs;
    }
    public void setOerLineWSs(List<OrderLineWS> orderLineWSs) {
        this.orderLineWSs = orderLineWSs;
    }

}
```

OrderLineWS.java

```
package com.dev.backend.order;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.dev.backend.product.ProductWS;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OrderLineWS implements Serializable{

    private Integer quantity;
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    private String productCode;
    private String orderCode;

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public BigDecimal getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }
    public void setUnitPrice(BigDecimal unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }
    public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }
    public void setTotalPrice(BigDecimal totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }
    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }
    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }
    public String getOrderCode() {
        return orderCode;
    }
    public void setOrderCode(String orderCode) {
        this.orderCode = orderCode;
    }

}
```

IWebService.java

```
package com.dev.backend.webservices;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.dev.backend.customer.CustomerWS;
import com.dev.backend.order.OrderWS;
import com.dev.backend.product.ProductWS;

@WebService
public interface IWebService {

    @WebMethod
    Integer saveOrder(OrderWS orderWS);
}
```

I generated classes on client side using this command

```
wsimport -Xnocompile . http://localhost:8080/WS/IWebService?wsdl
```

On client side OrderWS.java is generated like this

```
package com.dev.backend.webservices;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for orderWS complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="orderWS">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="customerCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="orderNumber" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="totalPrice" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "orderWS", propOrder = {
    "customerCode",
    "orderNumber",
    "totalPrice"
})
public class OrderWS {

    protected String customerCode;
    protected String orderNumber;
    protected BigDecimal totalPrice;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the customerCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCustomerCode() {
        return customerCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the customerCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCustomerCode(String value) {
        this.customerCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the orderNumber property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the orderNumber property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrderNumber(String value) {
        this.orderNumber = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the totalPrice property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the totalPrice property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public void setTotalPrice(BigDecimal value) {
        this.totalPrice = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide example classes ?

Comment: @frankelydiaz Added the example. Please help me out . Really need to solve it today.

Comment: @CornelCreanga Can you please help me out here.